# Determine tile size sequence

Tags: php, image, math, imagemagick, sequence

I have following tile values:

```
$tileheight = "58"; // 100x100  104px   560x560
$tileheight = "36"; // 200x200  104px   560x560
$tileheight = "32"; // 300x300  104px   560х560
$tileheight = "30"; // 400x400  104px   560х560
```

100x100...400x400 - height and width of generated image inside tile

104px - height of tile

560x560 - height and width that will always outputs (fits in image)

What would be the value - "?" for dimension 500x500? What formula could I use?

```
$tileheight = "?"; // 500x500 104px   560х560
```

Here for what result will outputs for 400x400:
[image: 400x400]

UPDATE:

Here what code I use for conversion:

```
exec("convert '$image' -resize ".$imgw."x".$imgh."! -quality 100 'proc/res$session.jpg'");

exec("convert '$tile' -resize x".$tileheight." -quality 100 'proc/til$session.jpg'");

exec("convert $image $pp -write mpr:image +delete \
proc/til$session.jpg -write mpr:edge_top +delete \
proc/til$session.jpg -write mpr:edge_btm +delete \
\
mpr:image -alpha set -bordercolor none \
-compose Dst -frame ".$tileheight."x".$tileheight."+".$tileheight." -compose over \
\
-transverse  -tile mpr:edge_btm \
-draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' -transpose -draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' \
-transverse  -tile mpr:edge_top \
-draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' -transpose -draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' \
\
mpr:image -gravity center -composite proc/ok$session.jpg");

$input = "proc/ok$session.jpg";
$toWidth  = "840";
$toHeight = "560";
$quality  = "100";
// -background white -gravity center -extent {$toWidth}x{$toHeight}
exec("convert $input -thumbnail {$toWidth}x{$toHeight} proc/ok$session.jpg");
```

Here what formula I use to make correct tile height:

```
$tiledata = getimagesize($tile);

$tilewidth = $tiledata[0];
$tileheight = $tiledata[1];

$math1 = ($tileheight+$tileheight)/($imgw+$imgh);
$tileheight = $tileheight * $math1;
```

Comment: Not enough information!  I think we need to see your commands.  But can you not just try various values of tileheight with image size 500x500 until you get the correct output image dimensions of 560x560? Perhaps I do not understand how you are using your tile height in your commands. Can you provide ImageMagick command line(s) that process your image to add the tiles?

Comment: CONTINUED: Given an inside image of NxN and tile thickness of m, then your output image will always be (N+2m)x(N+2m), provided you have not added any constant bordering between the inside image and the tiling or outside the tiling.  So I do not see how you get a 100x100 inside image with tile thickness of 58 to achieve a 560x560 size image. You would have to resize your inside image. Are you doing that?  Furthermore, you say you have tile thickness of 104 always, but your tileheight arguments are much smaller and twice that value is not 104. So what are you doing?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do - add a frame to a random size image? If so there is a method here: https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#frame_edge as well as discussions on the Imagemagick forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame has been added to the image before resizing.

You have an image of 400 pixels wide with a 30 pixels frame:

```
 400+2*30 = 460
```

To resize, you have to multiply by `560/460`, giving you the output you have in your sample jpeg : a 488x488 image with a 36px large frame. (36*2 + 488 = 560)

So, you have to consider that the values used are wrong because you do not obtain a 400x400 image. But it would be very difficult to use correct values as the tile is only 104px large which is impossible for a width lower than 352px.

You also have to consider than you should use a coordinate that match a new layer of the frame in order to be aesthetically acceptable.

A correct formula for image larger than 352px will be something like:

```
 $tileHeight = (560 - $expectedWidth) / 2;
```

EDIT : 
**From the examples of your original website, the frame width and height are constant before the final resizing to 560px.**

You have nothing to calculate!

```
 ## first we resize the original image to the size wanted 
 exec("convert '$image' -resize ".$imgw."x".$imgh."! -quality 100 'proc/res$session.jpg'");

 ## we add the frame edge by using the original width and size of the "$tile" file
 $tiledata = getimagesize($tile);
 $tilewidth = $tiledata[0];
 $tileheight = $tiledata[1];

 exec("convert 'proc/res$session.jpg' -write mpr:image +delete \
 '$tile' -write mpr:edge_top +delete \
 '$tile' -write mpr:edge_btm +delete \
 \
 mpr:image -alpha set -bordercolor none \
 -compose Dst -frame ".$tileheight."x".$tileheight."+".$tileheight." -compose over \
 \
 -transverse  -tile mpr:edge_btm \
 -draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' -transpose -draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' \
 -transverse  -tile mpr:edge_top \
 -draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' -transpose -draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' \
 \
 mpr:image -gravity center -composite proc/ok$session.jpg");

 ## and we resize to the desired final output size
 $input = "proc/ok$session.jpg";
 $toWidth  = "840";
 $toHeight = "560";
 $quality  = "100";
 // -background white -gravity center -extent {$toWidth}x{$toHeight}
 exec("convert $input -thumbnail {$toWidth}x{$toHeight} proc/ok$session.jpg");
```

Comment: It seems to me without seeing the input image and tiles that you need to resize your input image to a size smaller by 2*tilesize in each dimension, then add the tiles with the desired tile size.  Can you post an example input image with tile and the desired output for the tile size you want.

Comment: @kostya572 Those examples are definitely what we missed in your question : the output inner image does not have the expected size. This size is used to first apply the frame using its original size, and then it's finally resized to 560px.

Comment: @Adam Thanks, you directed me to the right way about tiles. The problem also was that this site scales up the inner image in about 2.4 times, that's why I couldn't find correct proportions. For what reasons thay scales up it I don't know. Maybe not to lose image quality output or for more attractive output.